# c++ lightweight lib supporting http POST

Tags: c++, http, post

do you know any?
I looked at winhttpsendrequest and threw up immediately - I need something that one can actually use.

I also need to modify the headers... Any suggestions?

EDIT: and by lightweight I mean very fast learning curve (I'm a beginner and I don't understand comlpex libraries...) . Plus, ideally few LOC.
But the learning curve is more important.

Comment: define 'lightweight': LoC, runtime, compile-time, learning-curve, ...?

Comment: Have you looked at POCO?

Comment: @AlanStokes I've just taken a look at POCO and sounds quite promising. One thing bothers me however - I read that POCO is not well-documented. Is that true? Because that aspect is absolutely crucial for me (I'm a beginner programmer and I can't read code well).

Comment: @Tomy Yes and no - there's a lot of pretty good documentation, but as soon as you dig down you find yourself on your own (and have to read the code). But even so it's probably better than most of the alternatives :-(

Comment: @AlanStokes I've been using Poco for the last 4 days and I must say like it  :) I've also taken some quick looks at the code and it is quite easy to read(at least the parts I read) ;) SO thank you for the suggestion one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

Once ran into [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/), initially headers-only, but now also static libaries, and aiming for boost submission.

I never had the opportunity to try it out, though.